# XPath logical 'and' not working as expected?

Tags: xml, xpath

Below is my XML output:

```
<information>
    <type>
        <slot>0</slot>
        <state>Online</state>
        <name>JAMES</name>
    </type>
    <type>
        <slot>3</slot>
        <state>Online</state>
        <name>Santa</name>
    </type>
</information>
```

I am looking for a way to get the value of slot as 0 and 3.

XPath:

```
/information/type[name="JAMES" and name="Santa"]/slot
```

expected output:

```
<slot>0</slot>
<slot>3</slot>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `and` to an `or`:

```
/information/type[name="JAMES" or name="Santa"]/slot
```

Even though you want to select 0 ***and*** 3, the logical property that you want to select is actually that the string value of the `name` element is `"JAMES"` ***or*** `"Santa"`.  It's the logical property that has to be placed in the predicate.